# How to load balance with two MySql server instance in zend framework application?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, zend-framework, load-balancing

I need to load balance Mysql server in zend framework application.

Can anyone please throw some light on how can I do this ?

I need to implement it with two MySql server instance running, one as Master and other as Slave using round robin algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

For the connection setup you can use [Zend_Application_Resource_Multidb](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.multidb). For per-client round robin you could change the server to connect next in you DB class. This will do round-robin for all queries during page load. You also could use memcache to make it application-wide.

Be aware that you have to suppress writes to the slave.

Comment: Aren't writes to slaves forwarded by the slave to the master? It's something I would expect not something that I heard of.

Comment: No, but you can set the slave in read only mode to ensure that you do not accidentally write to it